# return value from listWidget in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

Whenever I attempt to store the selected value from a listWidget using

```
foo=self.listWidget.currentItem()
```

this is what I get as a value for foo:

```
<PyQt4.QtGui.QListWidgetItem object at 0x023BDD68>
```

This sort of makes sense, but is clearly not what I was asking it for. I'm aware of round about ways to get the actual item selected but is there not some one line method for doing this, like there is for every other input widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [PyQt4 QListWidgetItem docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidgetitem.html#text), you could use:

```
item = self.listWidget.currentItem()
value = item.text()
```

Or on one line:

```
value = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: It is not on QListWidget main page, which is strange, easy to miss.